# Find index of word in string

Tags: c, string

I want to write a function which will find index of word in string.
For example if string is

> This is word.

my function for string "word" should return number 3.

- Note: functions from *string.h* library and auxiliary strings are not allowed.

How could I do this in C?

Comment: You can split the sentence by space to get the words and then match each word in the sentence with the word you want to match

Comment: @devec It is evident that you need to use loops.

Comment: Suggestion: think of the position starting at `0`... so position of `"word"` in `"This is word."` would be `2` ...  BTW: what about `"you're"`? Is it 1 word, 2 words? Illegal? Never happens?

Comment: _auxiliary strings are not allowed_ Does this mean that you could _not_ use `char wordlist[100][20];` to hold the individual tokens? Or, you could _not_ copy the string to a buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the sentence by space to get the words and then match each word in the sentence with the word you want to match
Please check this modified code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
 
int main()
{
    char word[] = "word";
    char string[100];
    gets(string);
    int curWordStart = -1;
    int curWordEnd = -1;
    int wordCount = 0;
    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; string[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (string[i] == ' ')
        {
            int curWordLength = curWordEnd - curWordStart + 1;
            if (curWordStart != -1 && curWordLength > 0)
            {
                wordCount++;
                int foundMatch = 1;
                int j;
                int k = 0;
                for (j = curWordStart; j <= curWordEnd; j++) {
                    if (word[k] == '\0') {
                        foundMatch = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    if (word[k] != string[j])
                    {
                        foundMatch = 0;
                        break;
                    }
                    k++;
                }
                if (word[k] != '\0')
                {
                    foundMatch = 0;
                }
                
                if (foundMatch == 1)
                {
                    printf("%d\n", wordCount);
                }
            }
            curWordStart = -1;
            curWordEnd = -1;
        }
        else if ((string[i] >= 'a' && string[i] <= 'z') || (string[i] >= 'A' && string[i] <= 'Z'))
        {
            if (curWordStart == -1) {
                curWordStart = i;
            }
            curWordEnd = i;
        }
    }
    int curWordLength = curWordEnd - curWordStart + 1;
    if (curWordStart != -1 && curWordLength > 0)
    {
        wordCount++;
        int foundMatch = 1;
        int j;
        int k = 0;
        for (j = curWordStart; j <= curWordEnd; j++) {
            if (word[k] == '\0') {
                foundMatch = 0;
                break;
            }
            if (word[k] != string[j])
            {
                foundMatch = 0;
                break;
            }
            k++;
        }
        if (word[k] != '\0')
        {
            foundMatch = 0;
        }
        
        if (foundMatch == 1)
        {
            printf("%d\n", wordCount);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It will print each position of the searched word in the sentence. If you want to just print the first one, you can easily modify it.

Comment: The question days **no auxiliary strings**, hence you cannot use the`curWord` array.

Comment: Missed that, sorry. I will try to modify it. @chqrlie

Comment: @chqrlie Just updated the code

Comment: The code is a little complicated and will not find the words `abc` or `def` in `abc,def`

Comment: The code seems complicated but the logic is easy to understand I guess. And I assumed that words are separated by space. The program can easily be modified to work on the case where words are separated by comma

Answer (score 1):

I can't think of a solution better than this (though there might be better ones).

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char word[] = "This is a word";
    int flag = 0, space = 0, pos = -1;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (flag == 1) {
                break;
            }
        for (int j = 0; word[j] != '\0'; j++) {
            if (flag == 1) {
                break;
            }
            else if (word[j+1] == '\0' || word[j+2] == '\0' || word[j+3] == '\0') {
                break;
            }
            else {
                if (word[j] == 'w' && word[j+1] == 'o' && word[j+2] == 'r' && word[j+3] == 'd') {
                    flag = 1;
                    pos = j;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        if (word[i] == ' ' || word[i] == '!' || word[i] == '@') {// And many more symbols
            fchars++;
        }
        else {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (flag == 1 && pos-1 > 0 && word[pos-1] == ' ') {
        for (int i = 0; i < pos; i++) {
            if (word[i] == ' ') {
                space++;
            }
        }
        printf("Found at position = %i\n", space+1-fchars);
    }
    else {
       printf("Not found!\n");
    }
    
}
```

Comment: This does not compute the word number, but the offset of `word` in the string. According to the question, it should return `4`, not `10`.

Comment: I guess this thing would make it easier now. Just calculate the spaces before `pos`.

Comment: What is the purpose of the outer loop? This code would find `word` in `password` and `wordless`

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Will make an edit again!

Comment: @onapte this doesn't ignore spaces, could modify it to work for "     This    is   word      "

Comment: and this works just for string "word"

Comment: @devec Please check my solution. It should work for any word.

Answer (score 0):

Here are steps to follow:

- you must specify precisely what is a *word* in the string.
- measure the length `len` of the word to search
- define an `int index = 1`
- in a loop, using a pointer `p` starting at the beginning of the string:

  - advance `p` past all word delimiters (spaces, punctuation or non letters?)
  - if `p` is at end of string return `0` (not found).
  - measure the length `len1` of the current word in the string
  - if `len1 == len` and all bytes are identical to those of the word, return `index`
  - otherwise skip the word by advancing `p` by `len1`, increment `index` and continue the loop.

Here is an implementation:

```
#include <stddef.h>

int isletter(char c) {
    /* assuming ASCII */
    return (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') || (c >= 'a' && c <= 'z');
}

int word_index(const char *str, const char *word) {
    const char *p = str;
    size_t len, len1, i;
    int index = 1;
    for (len = 0; word[len]; len++)
        continue;
    for (;;) {
        while (!is_letter(*p))
            p++;
        if (*p == '\0')
            return 0;
        for (len1 = 0; is_letter(p[len1]); len1++)
            continue;
        if (len1 == len) {
            for (i = 0; i < len && p[i] == word[i]; i++)
                continue;
            if (i == len)
                return index;
        }
        p += len1;
        index++;
    }
}
```